# WooCommerce Eway plugin not creating customer token for new customer

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, eway

I have setup a fresh docker container with Wordpress 5.0.3 and the latest WC and WC Eway plugin (WooCommerce eWAY Gateway).

Created a store with some products, hooked up my Eway sandbox environment, enabled Save Cards (which would enable the token) and created an order.
After checking the post_meta in my DB for the order, I didn't see a `_eway_token_customer_id` field. While being logged in as a customer, I tried again and with the new order I still do not get a token.

The reason for this tests is that I got this strange behaviour in my real, new website, where the first order with a NEW customer, doesn't result in a token.
However, when I create a second order whilst being logged in, I do get a `_eway_token_customer_id` value within the `order_meta`.

It is imperative for me to get that token with the first order, because after that I will auto renew the product using the tokenp ayment option.

Debugging this issue is hell, and I find it very disconcerting that on my fresh WP installation I get no token at all.

Is there anyone that has a bright idea?

**update
After some digging around in the Eway Plugin, I found out that the first time I do an order, the function `request_access_code()` from the class `WC_Gateway_EWAY`  is checking if there is a token in the database for this user.

The function body:

```
protected function request_access_code( $order ) {

        $token_payment = $this->get_token_customer_id( $order );

        if ( $token_payment && 'new' === $token_payment ) {
            $result = json_decode( $this->get_api()->request_access_code( $order, 'TokenPayment', 'Recurring' ) );
        } elseif ( 0 === $order->get_total() && 'shop_subscription' === ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ? $order->order_type : $order->get_type() ) ) {
            $result = json_decode( $this->get_api()->request_access_code( $order, 'CreateTokenCustomer', 'Recurring' ) );
        } else {
            $result = json_decode( $this->get_api()->request_access_code( $order ) );
        }

        if ( isset( $result->Errors ) && ! is_null( $result->Errors ) ) {
            throw new Exception( $this->response_message_lookup( $result->Errors ) );
        }

        return $result;

    }
```

The function handles three possible outcomes:

```
1) new customer: results in calling `$this->get_api()->request_access_code( $order, 'TokenPayment', 'Recurring' )` <-- this is the one we are after!

2) shop_subscription: calls `$this->get_api()->request_access_code( $order, 'CreateTokenCustomer', 'Recurring' )`

3) else..: calls `$this->get_api()->request_access_code( $order )`
```

What is happening during debugging, is that the `$token_payment` variable has the value of an empty string for a new customer, instead of `new`.
So I will attempt to fix this, either via a filter/action hook, or figure out why this is happening.

When I forced the function the always use the first `if` block, I got my token. :)

**Update 2:
I tested with an existing user account, created a new order.
When I look in the `post_meta` table:
[image]
Voila, the `new` value is present.

However, when I am not logged in and I create an account, the `new` value is not added and that is where it goes wrong.

A temp fix would be to use a hook and add the `new` value to the order so that when `get_token_customer_id` is called it retrieves a `new` value and not an empty string.

I think this is a bug, since this value should be added. It explains why the second transactions get the token but not the first.

If only Woocommerce Eway plugin had a git repo.... I could flag an issue or fork it.

***Solution without hack
Added this to my plugin (or functions.php if you like):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', function( $order_id, $posted_data, $order ) {
            update_post_meta( $order_id, '_eway_token_customer_id', 'new' );
        }, 10, 3);
```

This will add the new value when you checkout with a non-existent user.
The token was added nicely after adding my creditcard details.

The matter of the fact stays that the plugin still has a bug, which you can work around.

Comment: Sorry but you should report this bug to the the plugin authors… StackOverFlow don't handle any software support and *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"*.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I did post this whole story on their forum. However I was hoping to get help from people in the community that might have run into the same issue. Plus I provided a workable solution for now. Woocommerce is not very accessible support wise...(it actually really sucks). Plus I think my questions is pretty clear, and I wasn't sure I was making a mistake or there is bug. I now believe it is a bug.